# Is there a solution to the equation $tan({\phi})=\frac{0}{0}$

Tags: trigonometry, coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates

I've been reading about conversion from Cartesian ($x,y,z$) to Spherical (r, $\theta$, $\phi$) coordinates. The formula to find the value of ${\phi}$ is given as:

$\tan({\phi})=\frac{y}{x}$

My problems begin when I have a point in Cartesian coordinates like $(0,0,1)$.
To get $\phi$ I should find the value of

$\tan^{-1}(\frac{0}{0})$

and for me it does not make sense.

Intuitively and graphically, I can see $\phi$ can take any value, because $\theta=0$, but I cannot find a way to put the idea on paper.

Thanks.

Comment: The expression $\;\frac00\;$ is of course meaningless. The azimut angle $\;\phi\;$ is zero or $\;\pi\;$ for any point on the $\;z-$ axis (this may depend on the agreed range for the angle)

Comment: $0/0$ does not make sense.  Points on the $z$ axis do not have a unique expression in spherical coordinates.

Comment: Yeah, notice that at that point, you are directly above the origin of the 2-D Cartesian plane. $r$ is simple, 1. The azimuthal angle doesn't matter, because spherical coordinates are rotationally symmetric about the $z$-axis. $\theta$ is naturally 90º above the equator, so to speak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This equation breaks down for points on the $z$-axis, for a reason.

The three spherical coordinates, like you say, are $(r,\theta, \phi)$, or the radial distance, the polar angle, and the azimuthal angle respectively.

Your point, $(0,0,1)$ is directly above the origin on the 2-D Cartesian plane. It is a distance $r=1$ from the origin.

As for $\theta$ it is obviously $90º$ above the horizon, pointing directly up.

The reason the tangent formula fails is because it doesn't matter what $\phi$ is, though convention would have you leave it at $0$ or a similar number.

No matter how you rotate the point around the $z-axis$, it won't change position. If it were off the $z$-axis, then it would have either an $x$-coordinate, a $y$-coordinate, or even better, both.

Notice that if $x=0$, then $\phi$ is similarly undefined. This is because, if $x=0$, then it is geometrically evident that it is an angle of $\frac{π}{2}$ about the $z$-axis, and $\tan$ has an asymptote at that angle value.

Imagine, if you're looking down at the 2-D cartesian plane. The tangent formula is valid when $x≠0$. When $x=0$ just use common sense about what the angle must be (that is, $90º$ away from the positive $x$-axis, in some sense).